# what means '-' in microsoft dynamics nav 2009

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I am using microsoft dynamics navision 2009 and I see sometimes this sign:  `'-'`

what means  `'-'` in microsoft dynamics navision 2009?

For example this:

```
 IF FORMAT("Outbound Whse. Handling Time") <> '' THEN BEGIN
    LocTxtHandlTime := '-' + FORMAT("Outbound Whse. Handling Time");
  END ELSE BEGIN
    LocTxtHandlTime := '';
  END;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic sign `'-'` is a string `-` in quotes. For example `''` is an empty string and `'Apple'` is a string `Apple`. In programming the quotes are necessary. Read some intro book.